how do I format the wildcard inside the BOOLEAN expression so that it tests for all extensions?
I'm trying to sync two directories, Masters and Proxies, via a bash script:
# Loop through files in Proxy Files folder
for file in "$ProxyFilesDir"/*; do
  # Extract filename without extension
  filename_no_ext=$(basename ${file%.*})

  # Check if a file with the same name exists in Master Files folder
  if [[ ! -f "$MasterFilesDir/$filename_no_ext".* ]]; then
    echo "Deleting (proxy version) $file since master version was not found in $MasterFilesDir ..."
    rm -f "$file"
  fi
done

But the test fails with the wildcard "*" for any extension (can be multiple file types, while proxy is JPEG). It does work if I specify an extension.
I tried all this but still stumped:
tom$ if [[ -f /foo/Sandbox/Master-Files/master-2.txt ]]; then echo "files found"; fi

files found

    tom$ if [[ -f /foo/Sandbox/Master-Files/master-2.* ]]; then echo "files found"; fi

tom$

tom$ if [[ -f "/foo/Sandbox/Master-Files/master-2".* ]]; then echo "files found"; fi

tom$

tom$ if [[ -f '/foo/Sandbox/Master-Files/master-2'.* ]]; then echo "files found"; fi

tom$

tom$ if [[ find -f "/foo/Sandbox/Master-Files/master-2".* ]]; then echo "files found"; fi
-bash: conditional binary operator expected
-bash: syntax error near `-f'

tom$ if [[ -f "/foo/Sandbox/Master-Files/master-2".* ]]; then echo "files found"; fi

tom$


Welcome. There's a few formatting options in the post editor you may find helpful, including one for code. Could you EDIT your post to format your commands as code? This will do a long way towards making your post more readable.

Also, please ask a clear and direct question using a question mark. Right now you have a few statements, and you appear to expect readers to infer what you're actually asking. Help prevent confusion: clearly state your question in the post body.

I tried using the formatting, but it just made a bigger mess of the text (I promise to learn more on this). Question is simple:m how do I format the wildcard inside the BOOLEAN expression so that it tests for all extensions? i showed several I tried, none worked.

I suppose I could have just asked that, but thought I would show the whole intent

Showing your intent is fine and good, but you still need a question, and that question needs to be in the body of the question.

did you edit the post? bc it's edited.. IDK someone other than owner can do that.. Also I changed the question, is that more like what is expected here?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I applied the formatting, yes. It's often easier to write out the code, then select the section and apply the formatting. I've stated it a few times now though: the question needs to be in the body. Titles are something that gives an idea the topic and question, and the question needs to be clearly stated in the body of the post. I highly recommend that you spend a bit of time reviewing the Help section, and specifically the sections in there about how to ask good questions. It'll be to your distinct benefit.

[[ is not a normal command and words in its argument list don't have pathname expansion aka globbing applied to them. [/test with an unquoted wildcard would do the expansion but could uncontrollably produce multiple results and thus syntax errors. The direct way to get a safely testable value is to use command substitution which does glob and can output empty or nonempty depending:
if [[ -z "$(shopt -s nullglob; printf %s $masterdir/$basename.*)" ]]
then : not in master blah blah
fi

If it makes sense for the rest of your script you can set nullglob once globally instead of in each subshell.
But instead of probing each one individually, IF the number of distinct names in $masterdir is not too large for memory, and not so much larger than the number of names in $proxydir as to be wasteful, you could better do:
declare -A inmaster
pushd $masterdir || exit 1 
for f in *;do inmaster[${f%.*}]=1; done; popd

pushd $proxydir || exit 1 # to avoid the basename calls
for f in *;do 
  if ! (( ${inmaster[${f%.*}]-0} )); then : blahblah; fi
done; popd

